# PHP Mysql $Id Issues Cannot Retrieve Data Using only $id as parameter

Tags: php, mysql

I am having problem of getting the values from mysql / php and I would appreciate if someone could help me. My problem is that I have a table called albums and in that table I have 6 columns which are id, album_name, artist, company, genre, price.  I have written this code in my index.php:

```
<?php
                    $query = mysqli_query ($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM albums ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4 OFFSET 8");
                    while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                    $id = $result["id"];
                    $album_name = $result["album_name"]; 
                    $img = $result["image"]; 
                    $artist = $result["artist"]; 
                    $company = $result["company"]; 
                    $genre = $result["genre"]; 
                    $price = $result["price"]; 

                        echo "<div class='col-md-3 col-xs-6'>
                        <a href ='album_page.php?id=$id' target='_blank' class='box_link_hover'><div class='box'>
                        <div class='inside_box'>
                        <div class='small_title'>
                        <h4>$album_name</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class='photo_box'>
                        <img src=$img class='img_dim'>
                        </div>
                        <div class='info'>
                        <p>Artist: $artist</p>
                        <p>Company: $company</p>
                        <p>Genre: $genre</p>
                        <p>Price: $price</p>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='buy_now'>
                        <p>Buy Now</p></a>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>";
                }
                ?>
```

I have another page called album_page.php which i am sending from my index.php to album.php the $id in order to get the data from my database. In my album_page.php page i have this code:

```
<?php
$sql = mysqli_query ($dbconn, "SELECT id,album_name,artist,company,genre,price FROM albums WHERE id='$id'");
$id = $_GET["id"];
$album_name = $_GET["album_name"];
$artist = $_GET["artist"];
$company = $_GET["company"];
$genre = $_GET["genre"];
$price = $_GET["price"];
echo "<div class='col-md-4 right_box'>";
echo "<p>Album Name: $album_name</p>";
echo "<p>Artist: $artist</p>";
echo "<p>Company: $company</p>";
echo "<p>Genre: $genre</p>";
echo "<p>Price: $$price</p>";
echo "<div class='buy_now_box'>Buy Now</div>";
echo "</div>";
?>
```

What i would like to do is to send that $Id from my index.php and get all the data in my album_page.php using the $_GET. I would like to get all the data from my database with the $id = 5 for example. I have tried this using many paremeters for example:

```
<a href ='album_page.php?id=$id&image=$img&album_name=$album_name&artist=$artist&company=$company&genre=$genre&price=$price&buy_now=$buy'target='_blank' class='box_link_hover'><div class='box'>
```

and it is working fine but i would like to have the same result using only this:

```
<a href ='album_page.php?id=$id' target='_blank' class='box_link_hover'><div class='box'>
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using <?php echo <a href ='album_page.php?id=$id' target='_blank' class='box_link_hover'><div class='box'> ?> then it should work.

Comment: In your second script, set the variable $id (_$id = $\_GET["id"]_) **BEFORE** you are referencing it in the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i have found what the problem was. I had to write in my album_page.php this in order to grap the data:

```
$sql = mysqli_query ($dbconn, "SELECT id,album_name,artist,company,genre,price FROM albums WHERE id='$id'");
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
$id = $_GET["id"];
$album_name = $result["album_name"];
$artist = $result["artist"];
$company = $result["company"];
$genre = $result["genre"];
$price = $result["price"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works even better ;-)

```
$id = $_GET["id"]
$sql = mysqli_query ($dbconn, "SELECT id,album_name,artist,company,genre,price FROM albums WHERE id='$id'");
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
// ....
```